# Solving $\sin8x = \sin4x -2\sin2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not really sure what to do with an exercise like this, I can't seem to find the right identity to use here and would love some help.

> $$\sin8x = \sin4x -2\sin2x$$

Thanks.

Comment: $\sin 8x - \sin 4x = 2 \sin 2x \cos 6 x$. Also take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: @royi Your identity is false. For one thing, using $\sin x=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ you get $e^{8ix}$ and $e^{-8ix}$ on the LHS, but nothing of degree $\ge 4$ on the RHS.

Comment: For $x = \pi/4$, the first two terms are zero, and the last is $-2$. So it's not an identity. (Just making G. Sassatelli's remark more concrete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin 8x=2\sin 4x\cos 4x=4\sin 2x \cos 2x \cos 4x$$
and
$$\sin 4x=2\sin 2x\cos 2x$$
we have 
$$\sin 2x=0\implies x=k\pi \quad \operatorname{or} \quad x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2} $$
or
$$2\cos 2x \cos 4x=\cos 2x-1$$
therefore
$$\cos 6x+\cos 2x=\cos 2x-1$$
thus
$$\cos 6x=-1$$
$$x=\frac{k\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{6}$$
$$x=\frac{k\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: I realize that what you did is true, but I don't understand how, is there anywhere I can read about the identities that you used here?

Comment: $\sin 2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ and $2\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)$

Comment: Please check  it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin 8x=2\sin 4x\cos 4x\\\sin 4x-2\sin 2x=2\sin 2x(\cos 2x-1)\\$$
$$2\cdot2\sin 2x\cos 2x(\cos^2 2x-\sin^2 2x)=2\sin 2x(\cos 2x-1)$$
Making $\sin 2x\ne 0$ one has $$2\cos 2x(2\cos^2 2x-1)=\cos 2x-1\iff4\cos^3x-3\cos 2x+1=0$$
This cubic equation is factorizable $$(\cos 2x+1)(2\cos 2x-1)^2=0$$
Thus $$\cos 2x=-1$$ and $$\cos 2x=\frac 12$$ $$\sin 2x=0$$ You can finish now.